# Logs of nginx(non-root) container logs

Tags: docker, nginx, devops

What additional permissions do I need in dockerfile in order to see the logs of the container, I can see the openshift pod is accessible but logs are not rolling
Logs:

output of oc logs -f podname is as below

`/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/ /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up`

I am using nginx debian image

Permissions in dockerfile to the new user:
`/var/cache/nginx,/var/log/nginx,/etc/nginx,/etc/nginx/conf.d,/etc/nginx/nginx.conf,/var/log/nginx,/var/www/html,/var/run/nginx.pid`

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
docker logs <container-name>
```

to look at the logs

Comment: same logs are showing as with 'oc logs -f'

Answer (score 0):

Your logs need to be on STDOUT and STDERR for you to see the logs. [Here is an answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/599103/make-a-docker-application-write-to-stdout/634296#634296) that will help you do that with NGINX. You will have to create a custom image by adding one RUN command. But I think this should get you what you need:

Comment: Actually I was already using stdout and sderr in RUN instruction in my dockerfile snippets. Might be I am not using those symbolic link argument in proper sequence. Do they have a proper sequence in the docker file?

Comment: Also I am running nginx as non-root with debian buster slim image.

Comment: Try using it in the same sequence. Also being a non-root user does not make a difference. Also, these logs are stored on the host. You can try accessing them as well.

Comment: do I need to remove nginx user from nginx.conf file ?

Comment: Also I am not using "user nginx;" in nginx.conf. So, is that a mandate to add user line to the conf file?

Comment: All the required processes are running as non-root(better than before) but still logs are not rolling.

Comment: oc logs -f <podname> -  stuck in the beginning itself now

Comment: Shall I give access to tty group to the non-root user in my dockerfile?